# "Access Denied: You do not have access" error in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to do some experimentation with MSAL JS and ADAL JS libraries. I was able to get MSAL JS working fine by doing configuration at Azure Active Directory => "App Registrations (preview)". However when I switched to ADAL JS I get an error about needing version 2.0, so I think I need to use the regular "App Registrations" screen.

However, when I click on the regular "App Registrations" button I get:

> Access Denied
>
> You do not have access
>
> Looks like you don't have access
> to this content. To get access, please contact the owner.

I think it's odd that I can access the "preview" app registrations screen but not the regular one.

I saw somewhere online somebody suggested making changes at "User Settings", but that screen gives me the same error message. Going to "Users" I see 0 users, and it won't let me add any (the plus is greyed out).

The account I am using is just a personal account, it is not tied to any organization so there is no admin. I assume I should have full permission or be able to give it to myself, but can't figure out how.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the User Setting that you may be trying to access, in order to enable users to register their applications.. (if it's disabled for some reason) https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6mMC.png .. Is this personal account you mention associated with an Azure Subscription?

Comment: Thanks. No, I don't have it associated with a Azure Subscription, but since the "preview" app registrations works I thought the non-preview would. If I try to do something that requires a subscription (like create a DB) it asks me if I want to make a 30 days free subscription. If a subscription was required for "app registrations" shouldn't it prompt the same?

Comment: Also, I can't find any "Default Directory" screen like in your screenshot, but maybe it is because I don't have an Azure Subscription.

Comment: ok and the account you're using is probably a microsoft account like xyz@live.com, hotmail.com, outlook.com etc.? I'm trying to clarify that the account isn't associated with or isn't a guest user in some organization's Azure AD?

Comment: I can't really speak for the user experience in Azure Portal.. i.e. why you don't get a prompt for free subscription.. but I can tell you that ADAL JS library works with Azure AD v1 endpoint and in order to register your application with Azure AD and try things with ADAL, your account will need to be associated with some Azure AD tenant.. 2 ways that I can think of.. 1 - you take a trial subscription with this account which creates an Azure AD for you and adds your account to it or.. 2- someone else adds/invites your account to an already existing Azure AD tenant.

Comment: In the search box of the azure portal page header, enter the `Azure Active Directory`, it will open your aad page and show you sign-in user information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a Trial Azure account fixed this problem, so it appears one is needed to use the "App Registrations" section.

It is still a little unclear why an account is not needed for the preview mode, however.

Also, it would be nice if Azure would show a proper message saying an account is needed instead of a error message, but that is a minor point.